# Parse iOS: Checking for number in If statement

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I have an app and I am using the parse.com framework. I am having trouble with reading the number for my data in my data browser.  I have code in my app that goes like...

```
PFObject *object = self.objects[indexPath.row];

if (object[@"comments"] > 0) {

    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"commentCell"];

}

else {

    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"otherCell"];

}
```

The problem is, when I first ran this code it worked perfect. But when I changed the values in the data browser (a 'number' column called "comments") the value from 1 to 0 and then pull to refresh my PFQueryTableViewController, it still dequeues the "commentCell" instead of the cell without the comments.

Its like it either isn't checking right or I am doing something wrong because nothing changes.

I was beginning to think maybe my "if" statement is not the way to check for a number from the parse database. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: If comments isn't an `NSString` you should consider renaming it. For example, if comments was a number it could be `numComments`. If it is a boolean, it could be `hasComments`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `[object[@"comments"] intValue]` instead.

Comment: I feel kind of stupid for spending an hour on that... I loves yous.

Comment: Haha it happens, glad I could help. Please accept my answer if you can.